# skflow regression predict multiple values

Tags: python, neural-network, forecasting, tensorflow, skflow

I'm trying to forecast a time series: given 50 previous values, I want to predict the 5 next values.

To do so, I'm using the `skflow` package (based on TensorFlow), and this problem is relatively close to the [Boston example provided in the Github repo](https://github.com/google/skflow/blob/master/examples/boston.py).

My code is as follows :

```
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd

import skflow
from sklearn import cross_validation, metrics
from sklearn import preprocessing

filepath = 'CSV/FILE.csv'
ts = pd.Series.from_csv(filepath)

nprev = 50
deltasuiv = 5

def load_data(data, n_prev = nprev, delta_suiv=deltasuiv):  

    docX, docY = [], []
    for i in range(len(data)-n_prev-delta_suiv):
        docX.append(np.array(data[i:i+n_prev]))
        docY.append(np.array(data[i+n_prev:i+n_prev+delta_suiv]))
    alsX = np.array(docX)
    alsY = np.array(docY)

    return alsX, alsY

X, y = load_data(ts.values) 
# Scale data to 0 mean and unit std dev.
scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler()
X = scaler.fit_transform(X)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(X, y,
    test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
regressor = skflow.TensorFlowDNNRegressor(hidden_units=[30, 50],
    steps=5000, learning_rate=0.1, batch_size=1)
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)
score = metrics.mean_squared_error(regressor.predict(X_test), y_test)
print('MSE: {0:f}'.format(score))
```

This leads to :

> ValueError: y_true and y_pred have different number of output (1!=5)

at the end of the training.

And when I try to predict, I have the same kind of problem

```
ypred = regressor.predict(X_test)
print ypred.shape, y_test.shape
```

> (200, 1) (200, 5)

We can therefore see that the model is somehow predicting only 1 value instead of the 5 wanted/hoped.

How could I use the same model to predict values for several values ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've just added support for multi-output regression into `skflow` since this [#e443c734](https://github.com/google/skflow/commit/e443c7343e7a625f3c35874fc87a5f6eb9934250), so please reinstall the package are try again. If it doesn't work, please follow up on Github.

I also added an example of multioutput regression to [examples folder](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/skflow/multioutput_regression.py):

```
# Create random dataset.
rng = np.random.RandomState(1)
X = np.sort(200 * rng.rand(100, 1) - 100, axis=0)
y = np.array([np.pi * np.sin(X).ravel(), np.pi * np.cos(X).ravel()]).T

# Fit regression DNN model.
regressor = skflow.TensorFlowDNNRegressor(hidden_units=[5, 5])
regressor.fit(X, y)
score = mean_squared_error(regressor.predict(X), y)
print("Mean Squared Error: {0:f}".format(score))
```

Comment: I don't think this code works anymore. When `fit()` is called, the following error is thrown: `Shapes (?, 1) and (?, 2) are incompatible`. (I'm using version `0.10.0rc0`) I also created a new question about this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39192107/multiple-target-columns-with-skflow-tensorflowdnnregressor

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39935394/multiple-regression-output-nodes-in-tensorflow-learn/40164742

Comment: Your examples folder 404's

Comment: I believe this is a bug in Learn... submitted:  https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6849