# How to make contrib.learn (SKFLOW) regression predict multiple values (TensorFlow 0.12.1)

Tags: tensorflow, skflow

This is very similar to the question [skflow regression predict multiple values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34224826/skflow-regression-predict-multiple-values).  However, later versions of TensorFlow seem to rendered the answer from this question obsolete.

I would like to be able to have multiple output neurons in a TensorFlow Learn regression neural network (**DNNRegressor**).  I upgraded the code from the referenced question to account for breaking changes in TensorFlow, but still get an error.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow.contrib.learn as skflow
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

# Create random dataset.
rng = np.random.RandomState(1)
X = np.sort(200 * rng.rand(100, 1) - 100, axis=0)
y = np.array([np.pi * np.sin(X).ravel(), np.pi * np.cos(X).ravel()]).T

# Fit regression DNN model.
feature_columns = [tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column("", dimension=X.shape[0])]
regressor = skflow.DNNRegressor(hidden_units=[5, 5],feature_columns=feature_columns)
regressor.fit(X, y)
score = mean_squared_error(regressor.predict(X), y)
print("Mean Squared Error: {0:f}".format(score))
```

But this results in:

```
ValueError: Shapes (?, 1) and (?, 2) are incompatible
```

I don't seen any release notes about breaking changes that indicate that the method for multiple outputs have changed. Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [tf.contrib.learn.DNNRegressor](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/DNNRegressor) docs, you may use the  `label_dimension` parameter, which is exactly what you are looking for.

Your code line with this param will do what you want:

```
regressor = skflow.DNNRegressor(hidden_units=[5, 5],
                                feature_columns=feature_columns,
                                label_dimension=2)
```

The standard `predict()` returns an generator object. To get an array, you have to add `as_iterable=False`:

```
score = metrics.mean_squared_error(regressor.predict(X, as_iterable=False), y)
```